# GTX 1080t ti rans out of memory

Tags: deep-learning, classification, computer-vision, transfer-learning

I have 60000 images divided into two classes. I have tried to build transfer learning with pretrained ResNet50 but my new GTX 1080 ti returns -1 after couples of epochs. My guess is that it runs out of memory. Which is weird because with the same script and the same data I could successfully ran it on GTX 1050 ti. Everything is in tensorflow-gpu backend

I have installed CUDA 9.0 with cudnn 7.1.4 on ubuntu for GTX 1080 ti.
Here is nvidia-smi
[image]

And I see lack of ram:[image]

Comment: would you put your error message? Are you using TF?

Comment: @Media, I am using Tensorflow backend keras. Error is: Process finished with exit code -1

Comment: Can you run `nvidia-smi` and share the complete output ?

Comment: @flyingDope, it's updated

Comment: Driver version looks fine to me. Are you using the same version of **tensorflow** and **keras** in both the GPUs ? (you can also share which specific versions you are using)

Comment: @flyingDope, I did have different tensorflow 1.8 and cudnn 7.1.4 on GTX 1080ti. I removed everything and installed tensorflow 1.6-rc1 and cudnn 7.0.3. For now it's working fine. But my weights are in GPU RAM which is wierd.

Comment: That's good things working for you. Well, weights will obviously be in the GPU ram because they are the tensorflow variables which are related to the computation graph which itself is in the GPU memory.